# Firebase realtime data will not mount when page is refreshed

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The first time that we load the app, all of our data shows, but once I refresh the page the data does not show. How do I make sure that the data shows when the page is refreshed?

This is the code where I am pulling the firebase data from.

```
import firebase from '../initfirebase';

export function FirebaseTablePull(){
    let jobs = [];
    firebase.database().ref("1h5GOL1WIfNEOtcxJVFQ0x_bgJxsPN5zJgVJOePmgJOY/Jobs").on("value", snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(snap => {
            jobs.push(snap.val());
        });
    });
    return jobs;

}
```

This is the table that we are pulling the data from firebase into. It works when we first load the app but shows nothing when we refresh the page.

```
import { FirebaseTablePull } from './firebaseTablePull';
import TableHeader from './TableHeader.js';
import Footer from './Footer.js';

export default function SimpleTable() {
  let job = FirebaseTablePull();

  return ( 

    <section id='table'>
    <TableHeader />
    <table class="table">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
              <tr>
                  <th>Company</th>
                  <th>Location</th>
                  <th>Position</th>
                  <th>Date Posted</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {job.map(data => {
              
              return (
                  <tr>     
                  <td>{data.company}</td>
                  <td>{data.location}</td>
                  <td>{data.position}</td>
                  <td>{data.datePosted}</td>
                  </tr>
                  
              );
            
              })}
      
            
          </tbody>
          
      </table>
    <Footer />
    </section>
  );
```

}

Comment: Where is your UseEffect that will handle the components mounting/updating ?

Comment: To be honest, I tried to implement it a while ago, but didn't get it to work so if you could help me with that, that would be great. I don't really know where to start with that.

Comment: You need to pull data in useEffect() that will fetch data when refreshed..

Comment: Should I use useEffect() in my table component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a code snippet from one of my projects maybe it will help you

```
export const ProjectPage = ()=>{
    useEffect(()=>{
        let dbRef = firestore.collection("projects");
        dbRef.onSnapshot((result) => {//do something});},[]);
    
return( <div>{//some data and stuff}</div>);

}
```

this is useEffect without any dependencies on state variable and will run only once when components are mounted (while loading page)

just put your code where you pull data into useEffect hook